# Apache Jmeter ignoring post body

Tags: firefox, http-headers, jmeter, fiddler

I have a problem emulating a Http request in JMeter.

The basic task is to make JMeter emulate a request made in firefox, and then use that as the basis of a performance test.
However, i am having problems getting JMeter to include the post-header body.

Using fiddler, i recorded the request from firefox, which looks something like this.

```
POST http://*****:8001/XMLServlet?action=send HTTP/1.1
Host: *****
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://*****:8001/XMLServlet
Cookie: JSESSIONID=YpvCQGvFWshb6yyNsZvWZzHLLknNMpXRJ36vR7p0jxSp41Q3zlbj!-409403047
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------491299511942
Content-Length: 3125
-----------------------------491299511942
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="find"; filename="2010100010427.XML"
Content-Type: text/xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE DDT PUBLIC "*****" "*****">
<Some XML file/>
-----------------------------491299511942
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

Send
-----------------------------491299511942--
```

I made a login request in JMeter which works fine, but the actual post isn't behaving as expected.

I am using the "Send file with request" option to send the file, i have chosen the POST method, and in Post Body(raw) i have added

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: *****
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://*****:8001/XMLServlet
```

I would expect this to be included in the final request, but when i look at fiddler after executing fiddler, this is the result:

```
POST http://*****:8001/XMLServlet?action=send HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=LdyTQGsGzg0bSvbTKhF3grPhBYTKnY2TJ3CzLdB3Fwp8K7r2z2zN!-409403047
Content-Length: 2034
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=_bm2tmf-3Nv071ZvyhFKaWOc4RixWE_dNyLk
Host: *****:8001
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.1 (java 1.5)

--_bm2tmf-3Nv071ZvyhFKaWOc4RixWE_dNyLk
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="find"; filename="2010100000484.XML"
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE DDT PUBLIC "*****" "http://*****/sad.dtd">
<Some XML file/>

--_bm2tmf-3Nv071ZvyhFKaWOc4RixWE_dNyLk--
```

Why is JMeter ignoring the Post Body? And more importantly: How do i fix it?

Comment: You can record the scenario using the jmeter proxy and compare the result with your current samplers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you added to POST body are HTTP headers, not body. Headers can't be setupped in HTTP Request sampler. To send them, you should add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) with all those headers.

Comment: And that made perfect sense once someone pointed it out. Thank you very much